# Selenium Won't Find Any Elements on Amazon Using IE - Other Pages Work Fine

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I'm currently not able to find any elements on http://amazon.com

I've tried several different ways but always get:
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException
(Using Eclipse/Java)

Other sites work fine, and in other browsers I can use Selenium on Amazon without an issue. My code is as follows:

```
File file = new File("path/IEDriverServer.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
DesiredCapabilities capabilitiesIE = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
capabilitiesIE.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilitiesIE);

driver.get("http://amazon.com");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='field-keywords']")).sendKeys("Test");
```

The two lines after System.setProperty are to get around the security settings in IE that I can't change.

I've tried finding different fields using all the different methods with no luck. Putting waits in also made no difference.

The field I was trying to find was the search bar to type text into.

Any help or ideas are appreciated.

EDIT:
Trying //* at first would run on the start up page instead of amazon.com so I put a wait in. When I did that it now gives me the following error:

*Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to find elements on closed window*

Here is what the bottom portion of the code is now:

```
driver.get("http://amazon.com");
try {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
List<WebElement> all = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*"));
for(WebElement ele : all){
    System.out.println(ele.getText());
}
```

Code worked after adding the below line to the code:

```
capabilitiesIE.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INITIAL_BROWSER_URL, "http://amazon.com");
```

So the final code is something like:

```
File file = new File("path/IEDriverServer.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
DesiredCapabilities capabilitiesIE = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();    capabilitiesIE.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);
capabilitiesIE.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INITIAL_BROWSER_URL, "http://amazon.com"); 
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilitiesIE);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='field-keywords']")).sendKeys("Test");
```

Comment: You could try selecting any element at all (using //*) to see what the driver has access to. If that returns nothing it's possible the page hasn't loaded when the XPath is being executed, in which case you'd have to add a WebDriverWait.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry for the late response. I edited the post above to reflect trying what you suggested. The wait had to be added or else it would start running before the page loaded. Now it thinks the window is closed even though it clearly isn't. Note I don't have to do this for any other pages. Just amazon.

Comment: Adding capabilitiesIE.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INITIAL_BROWSER_URL, "http://amazon.com");

After the security line fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding

```
capabilitiesIE.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INITIAL_‌​BROWSER_URL, "amazon.com");
```

After the security line fixed it!